# Re-financing rental property in excess of original basis

Tags: united-states, mortgage, tax-deduction

Is the interest deductible on a rental property mortgage that is in excess of the original basis plus any improvements, less depreciation?

Comment: The only reason in could be in excess is if you take out cash, right? well, you can obviously not deduct taxes on cash you take out for yourself, as it is not rental property related.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, no. Only if used for improvement or expansion to the original property.

Answer (score 1):

The interest on a loan secured by a rental property is not deductible at all.

The interest on a loan *used* to buy (or improve) the rental property is deductible, regardless of where you got it from (you can take money from your credit card to buy a rental - it will be deductible).

The deductability is per the use of the money, not the source, with the cash-out up to 100K from your **primary** residence being the notable exception.